# python web page parsing when no HTML tags exist

Tags: python

Got this lovely webpage with nothing but text and I need some help getting certain lines formatted and also join multiple lines on one line

The web page is http://www.srh.noaa.gov/data/PHI/SRFPHI

I need the date of report and everything between these 2 lines:

```
  .FOR THE BEACHES OF NEW JERSEY AND DELAWARE... (include this)
  TIDE INFORMATION... (not this line, just prior)
```

Any ideas what to use?

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't a "here's my problem solve it" site.

Comment: just copy that much. Btw, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If there's no HTML tags, there's no web page parsing to do. At this point, you're just doing general string parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I load all the lines into a list, and go through that list with a for loop. I check if `.FOR THE BEACHES OF NEW JERSEY AND DELAWARE` is in that index in the list, if it is I create a temporary variable called line. I go until line is the same as `TIDE INFORMATION...`, then it won't print anymore because the if statement will never be true again.

```
import urllib
import sys

url = 'http://www.srh.noaa.gov/data/PHI/SRFPHI'

try:
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
except:
    print 'Invalid url.'
    sys.exit(1)

data = response.readlines()

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    if '.FOR THE BEACHES OF NEW JERSEY AND DELAWARE' in data[i]:
        date = data[i - 2]
        print date
        line = data[i]
        while line.strip('\n') != 'TIDE INFORMATION...':
            print line
            i = i + 1
            line = data[i]
```

Comment: Thank you heinst! Very helpful explanation and spot-on solution! Really appreciate your humble response!